# Is Torbjorn's turret destroyed upon death?

Tags: overwatch

**Is Torbjörn's turret destroyed upon death?** Or does it stay until it destroyed by an ennemy?

The only thing mentioned about his turret on the [wiki (gamepedia)](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Torbj%C3%B6rn) is this :

> Torbjörn constructs an enemy-tracking autocannon. He can use his hammer to upgrade it, increasing its health and adding a second cannon barrel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have a source for this besides personal experience, but Torbjörn's turret will remain upon death. It is only destroyed if you setup a new one, the enemy destroys it, or you switch heroes.

Comment: I suppose the turret also gets destroyed if Torbjörn leaves the match, i.e. you change to a different hero?

Comment: @Nolonar I believe so. I will have to test it to confirm though.

Comment: I am sure the turret diappears with Torbjörn without ever playing Overwatch. If not, entire team could cycle becoming Torbjörns and placing turrets everywhere.

Comment: @OrcJMR most likely, i just haven't tried it to confirm it. but i'm 99.9% sure that is correct

Comment: Yes it definitely gets destroyed if you change heroes, same with Symmetra's.  Which sucks when you're playing random-heroes mode, because your turrets get destroyed as soon as you respawn :(

Comment: Any hero-specific effect goes away if you change heroes.  This includes things like Symmetra's shields on other players.

Comment: @Powerlord i figured as much, but hadn't actually tested it myself to make sure.

Comment: I have seen a video where the turret is destroyed if it is mid-construction when Torbjorn dies - It's one of the "Overwatch Mythbuster" videos made by Musilsc.

Answer (score 2):

**No, but also yes.**

Torbjorn's turret will not be destroyed if you kill the Torbjorn while he has a functional turret. However, if you kill Torbrjon as his turret is *building* (build animation and gaining health from 0-150), then his newly placed turret will also be destroyed.

[Source at 1:11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MT1z2m_9ro)